# Enable "Allow this app to make changes to your PC" prompt in remote desktop sessions

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, path

I have a remote desktop session open. Both systems are Windows 10 Pro. I just installed a program on the remote system that didn't add itself to the path, so I need to add it manually.

However, the edit button is greyed out:
[image: Environment variables dialog during remote desktop session]

I have noticed that when I open the environment variables applet over the remote session, I never get the prompt to allow the app to make changes to my system, which could explain why I'm not allowed to make changes. I *do* get this prompt when I'm logged into a local session, and I'm able to edit the path.

How can I enable the admin privileges prompt for remote sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was due to how I was trying to access the path editing app. If you type "path" into the Windows search bar, the first result is "Edit environment variables **for your account**", and the "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your PC?" prompt never appears, because you're just editing *user* settings. You're not allowed to make system-wide changes here.

On the other hand, if you type "environment variables" in the Windows search, the first result is "Edit **system** environment variables" and the "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your PC?" prompt correctly appears. Clicking "Yes" allows the *system* path to be modified.

This behavior is consistent regardless of whether it's a remote or local session. I didn't realize I was typing different search terms.